# Cant get script to print out extra columns and rows from a limit input in PHP

Tags: php

So I am trying to write a PHP and HTML script that will print out a table when a limit is entered.
Say 20 was entered, it would print out 1-20. 
I am stuck on the part to print out the table from the input. Any suggestions?

Here's my code...

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Number Generator</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles.css">


    </head>
    <body>
        <center><h4>Prime Number Table Generator </h4>
        <div id="div1">
            <form action="" method="POST">
            <label for="limit">Enter Limit: </label>
            <input type="number" name="limit" placeholder="limit">
            <br>
            <input value="Submit" type="button" name="submit">


        </form>  
        <?php



     if (empty($limit)) $limit = '';

  for($a = $limit; $a <= 9; $a++)
{


    $b = 3;




     }
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$column = 10;
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";

for ($td=1; $td<=$column; $td++) {
echo  "<td>".$td. "</td>";


}
echo "</tr>";
     }
?>
                   <div class="float_center">

             <table style="width:100%">
                 <tr>
                 <center> <td colspan="10"><b>1-<?php echo $limit. ' ' ?> Prime Numbers are in RED</b></td></center>
                 </tr>

                 <tr>
                     <td></td>
                 </tr>

             </table></center>
                   </div>            
    </body>
</html>
```

I finally got 1-10 to  print out but then it wouldnt print out any more after I added script for the submit button.

Comment: By the way, I am verrry new to PHP

Comment: Do you want to print table dynamically from limit ?

Comment: dynamically? What do you mean?

Comment: creating table from 1 to $limit ?

Comment: Yes please. I am completely stuck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed your center tags because they were confusing me. Take a look at this code and let me know if it works for you!

[image]

```
<?php
    $columns = 10;
    $rows = 0;

    if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && isset($_POST['limit'])) {
        $rows = $_POST['limit'];
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Number Generator</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container mt-5" align="center">
            <h4>Prime Number Table Generator </h4>
            <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
                <label for="limit">Enter Limit: </label>
                <input type="number" name="limit" placeholder="limit" value="<?= $rows ?>">
                <br>
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>

            <table class="table table-border mt-5">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) : ?>
                            <td>Column - <?= $i ?></td>
                        <?php endfor; ?>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) : ?>
                        <tr>
                            <?php for ($x = 0; $x < $columns; $x++) : ?>
                                <!-- edit this section to represent your column rows -->
                                <td align="center">
                                    I am a row column!
                                </td>
                            <?php endfor; ?>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endfor; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I also added the bootstrap CDN because everything was pretty jumbled and I don't have your css file, obviously, so it was a way to align things. But feel free to replace it.

Comment: Thank you for the code. Is there a way to make it 10 columns? instead of rows?

Comment: Yes. You can just edit the section I commented on. Let me show you, I'll update code.

Comment: Thank your for the help, I am going to look up the code parts to understand it all. :)

Comment: I updated the code. I know you are just starting and this is good practice but keep in mind that you'd usually want to perform something like this with a JavaScript framework that more easily and dynamically lets you update the page without refreshing it. Something worth keeping in mind!

Comment: Quick question. Why does the output skip the multiples of 11?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It's an incremental for loop and it starts at 0 so if you have 11 as the control (row or column) it should loop 11 times 0-10 is 11. Is that the source of your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
// Default limit for display tables
$default_limit = 10;

$limit = ( isset( $_POST['limit'] ) ? (int) $_POST['limit'] : $default_limit );

// You don't want to iterate over the table element wrappers
<div class="float_center">   
    <table style="width:100%">

    for ( $i = 0; $i &lt;= $limit; $i++ ) :
        ?>
        <!-- Put all your html contents here -->

        <tr>
            <td colspan="10"><strong>1-<?php echo $limit. ' ' ?> Prime Numbers are in RED</strong></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr> 
    <?php endfor; ?>

    </table>
</div>
```